# Show EditText error when user is not focused on that editText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an editText that currently shows an error popover.

editText.setError("You have done something wrong");

Now I need a workflow such that, when user clicks on a button elsewhere, I need to set an error on the editText. But right now, only an error icon is shown.

My question is, is it possible to make it show the whole error text without the user actually clicking (focusing) on it?

Comment: did you fixed your issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution 1**

Call

```
editText.requestFocus()
```

before setting the error.

**Solution 2**

Use a TextInputLayout.

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/text_input_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

And in code

```
textInputLayout.setError("Error");
```

**Solution 3**

Custom view, up to you.

Answer (score 1):

I use that library [MaterialEditText](https://github.com/rengwuxian/MaterialEditText) which makes everything more simple... Everything is well explained in the [wiki page](https://github.com/rengwuxian/MaterialEditText/wiki).

**Helper Text and Error Text**

helper text:

```
app:met_helperText="Integer"
```

error text:

*just use original setError(CharSequence error) in java code.*

regex check:

```
validationEditText.isValid("\\d+");
```

regex validate with error text setting:

```
validationEditText.validate("\\d+", "Only Integer Valid!");
```